# Running Sum ERRO

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Preciso fazer um running Sum em cada elemento de uma unica coluna de um DataFrame.
Para isso, preciso somar o elemento atual da coluna do df com o ultimo, por exemplo:

Se eu tiver uma coluna do DF, por exemplo uma coluna chamada numeros

```
exemplo=df['NUMEROS']
```

E essa coluna tivesse esses resultados aqui:

| NUMEROS |
| --- |
| 21 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 21 |
| 81 |
| ... |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |

A soma teria que ser tipo:

resultado= [21,21+2,21+2+1,21+2+1+21...]

Toda maneira que fiz está dando erro

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método [`pandas.DataFrame.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) ou [`pandas.Series.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) que retornam a somatório cumulativo em um eixo dum [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) ou de uma [Serie](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"NUMEROS": [21,2,1,21,81,2,2,1,1,1]})

#Faz o somatório cumulativo da serie df["NUMEROS"] e adiciona como a coluna ACUMULADO do DataFrame
df["ACUMULADO"] = df["NUMEROS"].cumsum()

print(df)
```

```
   NUMEROS  ACUMULADO
0       21         21
1        2         23
2        1         24
3       21         45
4       81        126
5        2        128
6        2        130
7        1        131
8        1        132
9        1        133
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Cumulative#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Ola você quem votou negativo, poderia informar qual o problema com essa solução? Expresse sua expertise, faça valer o seu voto pois suas orientações nos ajudariam muito a trazer cada vez mais conteúdo de qualidade a comunidade.